# executing the customs command on linux with process builder in java

Tags: java, linux, shell

I've been struggling for a while now with this problem and i can't seem to fix it. i have tried  `ProcessBuilder` for  executing the custom command on linux terminal but its not working

Actually i have two `.sh` file `setProto.sh and setTls.sh` file which is used to set the environment.So for executing the command i need to run these two  file first for each instance of linux terminal.Only then we can be able to run the custom command `anloss` on the same instance of linux terminal in which .sh file supposed to run.For some reason i'm not able to make it work what is the mistake in my code ? Here's the code.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.lang.ProcessBuilder.Redirect;

public class EngineTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder(
                    "/. setProto.sh",
                    "/. setTls.sh",
                    "/anloss -i ${TOOL_INPUT}/census_10000_col5.csv  -d ${TOOL_DEF}/attr_all_def.txt -q k=14,dage=2 -g ${TOOL_RES}/census_100_col8_gen.csv");
            builder.directory(new File(System.getenv("HOME") + "/PVproto/Base"));
            File log = new File("log");
            builder.redirectErrorStream(true);
            builder.redirectOutput(Redirect.appendTo(log));
            Process process = builder.start();

            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
            String line = "";
            String output = "";
            while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                output += line + "\n";
            }
            System.out.println(output);
            int exitValue = process.waitFor();
            System.out.println("\n\nExit Value is " + exitValue);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Process does not by default execute in the context of a shell; therefore your shell scripts cannot be executed the way you tried.

```
ProcessBuilder pb =
    new ProcessBuilder( "/bin/bash",
                        "-c", 
                        ". setProto.sh && . setTls.sh && /anloss -i ${TOOL_INPUT}/census_10000_col5.csv  -d ${TOOL_DEF}/attr_all_def.txt -q k=14,dage=2 -g ${TOOL_RES}/census_100_col8_gen.csv" );
```

I am not sure about `/anloss` - it's unusual for a command to be in root's home `/`. (Also, the `/.` you had there in front of the shell scripts - what should they achieve?)

**Later**

Make sure to replace `/anloss` with an absolute pathname **or** a relative pathname relative to `$HOME/PVproto/Base`, e.g., if it is *in* this directory, use `./anloss`, if it is in `$HOME/PVproto/Base/SomeSub`, use `SomeSub/anloss`, etc.

Also, if setProto.sh and . setTls.sh are not in `$HOME/PVproto/Base`, use an appropriate absolute or relative pathname. If they are, use `./setProto.sh` and `./setTls.sh` to avoid dependency on the setting of environment variable PATH.

Comment: /. for script  is to run on current directory and /anloss is not in root.If u see my code i have added builder.directory(new File(System.getenv("HOME") + "/PVproto/Base")); this is the path where all script and command has to run.if i made any mistake please do tell me.

Comment: i have tried ur way but its throwing error "cannnot run program /bash/bin"(in directory "/home/cloudera/PVproto/Base"): error=2,No such file or directory

Comment: The program is called `/bin/bash` (*not* /bash/bin) which must be there if it's Linux. You might also use `/bin/sh`.

Comment: Setting a **working directory** has not the influence you think on the way pathnames for program errxecution need to be specified. If you set the working directory to /home/henry, then you may execute a file in this directory using ./aProgInHenry.exe, but if the program is elsewhere, specify an absolute pathname. `/anloss` *is* an **absolute pathname** and instructs the system to go to the root directory.

Comment: Starting a command with `/.` to "run on current directory" - from where did you take this idea? `/.` is an absolute pathname referring to the root directory, i.e., `/`. (Try `ls /.` from a shell prompt.) If this is first in a command, it'll just try to call a program called `/`, which, of course, is nonsense.

Comment: I have added instructions for replacing "/anloss", which is clearly wrong.

Comment: i have given the absolute path but i am getting  exit value as 126 as error code. I have give like this   new ProcessBuilder("/bin/bash","-c","/home/cloudera/PVproto/Base/. setTls.sh && /home/cloudera/PVproto/Base/. setProto.sh && /home/cloudera/PVproto/Base/anloss -i ${TOOL_INPUT}/census_10000_col5.csv  -d ${TOOL_DEF}/attr_all_def.txt -q k=14,dage=2 -g ${TOOL_RES}/census_100_col8_gen.csv")

Comment: This part is incorrect: "/home/cloudera/PVproto/Base/. setTls.sh && /home/cloudera/PVproto/Base/. setProto.sh ..." Please follow the extended advice in the updated answer.

Comment: Where's this idea of a directory name as a separate word in front of a command's name coming from??

Comment: i have checked the permission on all file it is rwxr-xr-x including sh and anloss file

Comment: This I do believe. Please fix the invocations of those shell scripts!

Comment: issue fixed, problem is with my script file that contain #!bin/bash ,i removed that, now exit code is coming 0 thnx for the help.One more question here  is ,i am running command but output of that command is not coming in my eclipse console does i have make any mistake in my code for reading the output?

Comment: Standard output should appear there, but is "that command" really writing to *standard output*? Chancge String output = ""; to String output = "Output: "; and see what happens.

Comment: no ouptut is visible instead of "Output:", but when i append >test12 in front of my command , output is coming to this test12 file can u please tell why its happening

Comment: Try moving this statement: `int exitValue = process.waitFor();` up after `Process process = builder.start();`. Thus, the process completes and all standard output is available before you read it in the loop. - BTW, don't collect it all into a String `output`, simply `System.out.println( line );` with a line after you have read it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use Runtime.exec() for executing the commands on linux. I suppose you are executing your java code on linux machine where linux scripts needs to be run.

Below code snippet will help you in resolving it.

```
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(scriptWithInputParameters);
int exitCode = process.waitFor();
if (exitCode == 0) {
    System.out.println("Executed successfully");
}
else {
  System.out.println("Failed ...");
}
```

Please note you need to handle error and output stream in different threads to avoid buffer overflow.

If the above works for you then [this article](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2071275/core-java/when-runtime-exec---won-t.html) will help you further